# Windows Hello removing fingerprint by itself

Tags: windows, windows-hello, biometrics

I'm trying to push biometrics using GPO, below the settings applied. It works as I wasn't able to set it up but now Windows allows me to do so.

Yet every time I restart, fingerprint and PIN get removed. If I don't restart it will remove itself after an hour or so. I put myself in a new OU with heritance disabled so I'm completely isolated from any other GPO's. We don't have Intune yet, so that's not pushing anything either.

I'm just at a complete loss, I've tested it on a test device with W11 installed (it's a different type of laptop as well) and it's working fine there. Does anyone have any idea? I can't seem to find anything in event viewer either...

[image]

Comment: See if [these fixes](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-hello-fingerprint-not-working/) can help.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more thorough. I've done all of that and more (WinBioDatabase + NGC folder cleanup). It just keeps getting removed. I tried now with disconnecting the laptop entirely, that works. So it's something that gets pushed, but doesn't get pushed to the same account in the same OU to a different laptop.

Comment: The question is what is different in the GPO rules for your computer. Compare perhaps with the other computer. Places that might pertain: Registry keys `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\Settings\AllowSignInOptions` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System` and in GPO `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Biometrics` and perhaps others.

Comment: These are all the same as well, it's the "others" that might be the issue but I can't seem to find the right documentation on this.

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). Also run `chkdsk`.

Comment: Hi, did this all yesterday, still no luck...

Comment: All I can think of is [Repair Install](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/). This is the same as a major Windows upgrade, so take the same precautions.